# how to add comments in table row in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a appointments table & need to add a comments column in the table where comments could be updated when the user types in the text box and click submit. i have tried the code below but cant understand why it does not function correctly. I've did a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!
[image: Here is an img of the app table]
Here is my code:

```
<!--    <form method="post" action="delete.php" >   --> 
          <form method="post" action="tea_appview.php">  

       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">
            <!--      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered" id="example">  -->
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                                <th>appoinment ID</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>time</th>
                                <th>subject</th>
                                <th>Appointment from [parent]</th>
                                <th>Appointment to (teacher) </th>
                                <th> accept/reject </th>
                                <th>state</th>
                                <th>comm</th>
                          </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                        <?php 
                            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id
                            left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
                            ORDER BY app_id DESC"); 

                        if($query === false)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn));
                                }
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                {
                                    $ann_id=$row['app_id'];
                                    $date=$row['date'];
                                    $msg=$row['time'];

                                    $username = $row['username'];
                                     $username = $row['p_username'];
                                     $sub = $row['sub'];
                        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo date('j/m/y',strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['sub'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>

                    <td>
                       <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=reject";?>" class="reject">reject</a>
                        <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept";?>" class="accept">accept</a> 
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>


                <td><input type="text" name="comm">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </td>  
                </tr>

                        <?php  
                            //---------PROBLEM IS HERE-----------------------
                            //if(isset($_GET['app_id'], $_POST['submit'])!="")
                            if(isset($_GET['app_id']) && $_POST['submit'] !="")
                            {
                                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET comm = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['comm'], $_GET['app_id']);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $stmt->close();
                            }
                            //-------------------------------
                            if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id']))
                            {
                                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id']);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $stmt->close();
                            }



                      }

                       ?>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Is your ID really a double? I think it is an integer, so it should be a i. `"si"`

Comment: @Lithilion yeah it is an int...as u said i changed it to `"si"` but still it is not updated in the db

Comment: What does the code do? Whats the output?

Comment: @Lithilion i have two users where user1 could add an appointment and user2 must provide a comment  on it. thee comment must be written in the text filed which is available in the table

Comment: omg - user input going directly into the DB. There is no indication that _a comments column_ even exists in whatever table is being updated. We need more than the HTML form.

Comment: I mean whats the error? Is there an error message?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov - it is possible to use the method POST in the form element and also include query parameters in the `action` attribute URL ( both GET & POST from same form)

Comment: @Lithilion NO error msg but the table in the db is not updated

Comment: `$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from app left join par on par.par_id=app.par_id 
left join tea on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id 
ORDER BY app_id DESC");`
**i need to select the records only of the logged in tea (teacher) can someone help me on how to do it** @SalimIbrogimov @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your form tag

```
<form method="post" action="file.php?app_id=VALUE&state=VALUE">
```

You have to fill out your action with the file your code is processed with and the variables in your `$_GET` parameters. Also check this

```
if(isset($_GET['app_id']) && $_POST['submit'] !="")
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't directly answer the issue. Now that we have some code to look at you found it first and get the prize. :-)

Comment: The reason my earlier (now deleted) suggestion didn't change anything, or answer the question, or fix your problem is this:  (`"" === false`), and (`!"" === true`); Therefore, your test says `if (isset() !== "")` I'll let you rationalize about the rest of the statement. Your code is incorrect and should be fixed. But, as you point out, and I've acknowledged,  doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Edit your code above to show us what edits you've made. Let's see the edits Lithilion suggested.

Comment: `app_id=VALUE&state=VALUE` should  i put this line as it  is @RandyCasburn

Comment: file.php is like your file is named, and replace VALUE with your own value you want to submit

Comment: @Lithilion i already set a value to be passed for app_id and state therefore i replaced file.php with the same name of the file

Comment: @Lithilion  `CODE UPDATED`

Comment: You need to add the `?app_id=YOUR_VALUE_HERE&state=YOUR_VALUE_HERE` too, otherwise no data will get send to the form

Comment: @Lithilion can i add a ? for the  app_id and state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166210/discussion-between-lithilion-and-the-kingmaker).

Comment: @RandyCasburn do u have any ideas